# iCheck radiobox with white background

Tags: html, css, icheck

I am using [iCheck](http://icheck.fronteed.com/) to style my check- and radio boxes. I want to make the background of the radio box white. Currently its transparent and looks like this:

[image]

I thought it might be a good idea to edit the blue.png image

[image]

and to change the background from transparent to white. But now, the radio box is not smooth round anymore. This is how it looks now:

[image]

Is there any simpler/ better way to change the background to white? Do I really need to edit the blue.png?

Here is the code to produce the picture:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/vendor/icheck-1.x/skins/square/blue.css">
    <style>
    span{
      margin-left: 10px;
      color:#FFF;
    }
    label{
      background-color: #08C;
      border-radius:20px;
      padding: 20px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label for='name' >
      <input type="radio" name='name' id='name'><span>Select this name</span>
    </label>
  </body>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/resources/vendor/jQUery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
  <script src='/resources/vendor/icheck-1.x/icheck.js'></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $('input').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
        radioClass: 'iradio_square-white',
        increaseArea: '20%', // optional
      });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

**Edit** Here is the modified blue.png

[image]

You can download the uncompressed image [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=78173324402148219777&t=7817332440214821977705943).

Comment: Do you have a live demo somewhere?

Comment: @Frutis Sorry I am using XAMPP on my local desktop. I can't setup a jFiddle because I do not know how to import the icheck dependencies.

Comment: Can you upload your modified blue.png and add it to the question?

Comment: @CandyGumdrop Sure I have added it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest to change the style of those checkbox graphics than changing those images.  It may be possible to achieve a similar effect in CSS using `radial-gradient` or `border-radius` following the selectors in `blue.css` to produce a circle, but you are better off editing the graphic of the theme itself.

Your image doesn't look smooth because you filled in the background in such a way that removes antialiasing.

Here's `blue.png` and `blue@2x.png` with the background filled in as you have done, preserving antialiasing, using GIMP.

Note that your style is hard to see over a white background.

[image: blue.png]

[image: blue@2x]

Answer (score 0):

There is simpler than changing the png for sure.

I added a background-color to the color I wanted in .icheckbox_square-xxx, .iradio_square-xxx by adding the following in my own css file.

```
.icheckbox_square-grey, .iradio_square-grey {
   background-color: white;
}
```